# Click back counter

Tags: php, back

Hello i have this code which works for redirect back
Redirect Users leaving your site - Javascript back button hack

```
    <?php
$javascript = <<<DOC
<script>
var ref = document.referrer;
var siteurl = "YOUR URL HERE";//if you have www, then use www. http://www.yoursite.com
if (ref.indexOf(siteurl)!= -1){
}
else{
(function(window, location) {
    history.replaceState(null, document.title, location.pathname+"#!/auth");
    history.pushState(null, document.title, location.pathname);

    window.addEventListener("popstate", function() {
      if(location.hash === "#!/auth") {
        history.replaceState(null, document.title, location.pathname);
        setTimeout(function(){
          location.replace("http://www.blackhatworld.com/");
        },0);
      }
    }, false);
}(window, location));
}

</script>
DOC;

echo $javascript;
?>
```

I want to add it a counter that will only redirect after 3 clicks on back.
How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

try this javascript code :

```
<button id="button">Click Back 3  Times </button>
    <script>
      var counter = 0;
      $("#button").click(function () {
        counter++;
        if (counter == 3) {
          window.history.back();
        }
      });

    </script>
```

Comment: i dont want a button... i want to add the counter in the code i wrote so the redirect will happen only after 3 clicks

Comment: you meaning click anywhere ?

Comment: meaning click on the back button of the browser

Comment: it didnt work... can u add the counter to the 2nd code i showed?

Answer (score 0):

This code also works but i need to add the counter
this code which works for redirect back Redirect Users leaving your site - Javascript back button hack:

```
<script>
// managage back button click (and backspace)
var count = 0; // needed for safari
window.onload = function () { 
    if (typeof history.pushState === "function") { 
        history.pushState("back", null, null);          
        window.onpopstate = function () { 
            history.pushState('back', null, null);              
            if(count == 1){window.location = 'http://google.co.il';}
         }; 
     }
 }  
setTimeout(function(){count = 1;},200);

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking for a code to make redirect to page after clicking browser back button on the 3rd time... first 2 clicks should remain at the page